# RapidSSL with OCS Edge Servers

Tags: ocs

Can I use a certificate issued by RapidSSL for an OCS Edge Server installation?

Answer (score 0):

Your CA has to be one of those that is trusted by a default installation of Windows in order to be used for OCS federation purposes. I don't see RapidSSL in the list on my W2k8 box.